# Hanging Linq query with Guid.Empty in the where expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, csla

I'm having an issue with the following code:

```
    private void DataPortal_Fetch(TaskCriteria criteria)
    {
        using (var ctx = ContextManager<Gimli.Data.GimliDataContext>
                    .GetManager(Database.ApplicationConnection, false))
        {
            this.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
            this.IsReadOnly = false;

            IQueryable<Data.Task> query = ctx.DataContext.Tasks;

            if (criteria.ReadyForPricing)
            {
                query = query.Where(row => row.IsPriced != true);
                query = query.Where(row => row.Status == (int)TaskStatus.Closed);
                query = query.Where(row => row.InvoiceId == Guid.Empty);
            }

            if (criteria.ReadyForInvoicing)
            {
                query = query.Where(row => row.IsPriced == true);
                query = query.Where(row => row.Status == (int)TaskStatus.Closed);
                query = query.Where(row => row.InvoiceId == Guid.Empty);
            }

            var data = query.Select(row => TaskInfo.FetchTaskInfo(row));

            this.AddRange(data);

            this.IsReadOnly = true;
            this.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        }
    }
```

My web application, when it calls this method, always hangs if I don't comment out the following line:

```
query = query.Where(row => row.InvoiceId == Guid.Empty)
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works ... interestingly enough ... any idea of why?

```
query = query.Where(row => row.InvoiceId == new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
```

Comment: What happens when you run a SQL Server Profiler trace?  Do the two queries look different on the SQL server end?

Comment: Good question ... I'm going to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
query.Where(row => object.Equals(row.InvoiceId, Guid.Empty))
```

Post back if that helped...

Comment: Still hangs ... really odd.  I can run the same query in LinqPad and it works just fine.

Comment: Hmm, figured it was worth a shot. I got nothing else.. sorry!

Comment: Thanks ... I appreciate it!  Got the following to work new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") ... instead of Guid.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

@BFree ... Tried what you suggested ... and still do the same thing.  It's odd, I can run the following code in LinqPad with no problem:

```
from t in Tasks
where  t.IsPriced == false
&& t.IsNotInvoiceable == false
&& t.Status == 5
&& t.InvoiceId == Guid.Empty
select t
```

As well as I can use the following line of code with not problems either:

```
if (criteria.ProjectId != Guid.Empty)
     query = query.Where(row => row.ProjectId == criteria.ProjectId);
```

It's just when I use Guid.Empty. Just plain odd.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of how the lambda is interpreted; with "Guid.Empty", the "Guid.Empty" is part of the final lambda. I wonder whether the LINQ-provider is treating this as a special case somehow?

You could try:

```
Guid empty = Guid.Empty;
query = query.Where(row => row.InvoiceId == empty);
```

But actually, other than `Guid` vs some compiler-generated capture class, the expression tree for this is the same (they both involve lambda=>BinaryExpression=>MemberExpression).

If the above *also* complains, then try putting a TSQL trace on, or enabling your LINQ-providers logging - for LINQ-to-SQL, something like below works (don't quote me!):

```
ctx.Log = Console.Out;
```